# How to do refresh token in rust with reqwest as http client

Tags: authentication, rust, reqwest

I have an API client in my rust project, which is implemented using reqwest.
It is using jwt as authorization, and that jwt may expire.
Is there any way to do someting like "refresh token and send the request again"?
Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [oauth2](https://docs.rs/oauth2/latest/oauth2/) crate, which under the hood supports reqwest as an HTTP client.  You would need to check if you have a valid access token, and [request](https://docs.rs/oauth2/latest/oauth2/struct.RefreshTokenRequest.html) a new one as required.